# Rectangle class java with separate tester

Tags: javascript, methods, variable-assignment

So my goal is to get a program working that has multiple methods to manipulate rectangles.So far most of my code works but when I use my tester I am getting errors.  Any insite would be most appreciated!
First is my Tester Class.

```
 public class MyTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Rectangle i = new Rectangle(5,8);
    Rectangle p = new Rectangle(8,5);
    Rectangle o = new Rectangle(4);
    Rectangle n = new Rectangle();

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------"); //line seperation per testers

    //this prints out the width and height to the user (2 arg construct)
    System.out.println("i width: " + i.getWidth() + "\n" + "i height: " + i.getHeight());

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    //This prints out the width and height to the user (1 arg construct)
    System.out.println("o width: " + o.getWidth() + "\n" + "o height: " + o.getHeight());

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("n width: " + n.getWidth() + "\n" + "n height: " + n.getHeight());

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Here is the duplicate d of rectangle duplicate: ");// rectangleDuplicate
    System.out.println("Fix this sections of the tester and code!");

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    //This prints out to the user if Rectangles are equal or not
    System.out.println(i.equals(p));

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    //This prints out to the user the new width and height after rotating
    System.out.println(i.rotate());

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    //This prints out to the user the area of the selected rectangle
    System.out.println("The area of Rectangle o: " + o.getArea());

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    //This prints out to the user the diagonal of the Rectangle selected
    System.out.println("The diagonal of Rectangle p: " + p.getDiagonal());

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("A copy of Rectangle i: " + i.copy());//.copy
    System.out.println("Fix this sections of the tester and code!");

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println(p.scale());//.scale
    System.out.println("Fix this sections of the tester and code!");

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Lets double the area and pull the new width and height for Rectangle o: " + o.doubleIt());//.doubleIt
    System.out.println("Fix this sections of the tester and code!");
    }
```

}

Second is my Rectangle Class

```
 import java.util.*;
```

public class Rectangle {

```
//Data
private double width;
private double height;
public Rectangle(double w, double h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
}



//One no-arg constructor that constructs a rectangle 1X1
public Rectangle() {
    width = 1.0;
    height = 1.0;
}



//One one-arg constructor that takes one double argument, and constructs a square that size
public Rectangle(double sameSides) {
    width = sameSides;
    height = sameSides;
}



//One two-arg constructor that takes two double arguments, and constructs a rectangle that size
//Getters and Setters
public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
}
public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}



//One one-arg constructor that takes a Rectangle as an argument, and constructs as new Rectangle of identical size
public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangleDuplicate){ //calling rectangleDuplicate
    Rectangle d = new Rectangle();
    d.width = rectangleDuplicate.getWidth(); //set width to width of rectangleDuplicate
    d.height = rectangleDuplicate.getHeight(); //set height to height of rectangleDuplicate
}





//A ".equals()" method that accepts another Rectangle as argument, and returns TRUE if the other rectangle has an area within 1% of the instance rectangle.
public boolean equals(Rectangle p){
    double areaTest = (this.getArea()) / (getArea());
    if (areaTest <= 1.01 && areaTest >= 0.99){
        System.out.println("The area's are within 1% and thus are declared the same.");
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("These two Rectangles are not the same.");
        return false;
    }
}

//A ".rotate()" method that reverses height and width of the instance rectangle.
public boolean rotate(){
    double newWidth = height;
    double newHeight = width;
    System.out.println("The new width is: " + newWidth + "\n" + "The new height is: " + newHeight);
    return true;
}




//A .getArea()" method that returns the area of the rectangle.
public double getArea() {
    double area = width * height;
    return area;
}


//A ".getDiagonal()" method that returns the diagonal of the rectangle.
public double getDiagonal() {
    double diagonal = 0;
    diagonal = (width * width) + (height * height);
    diagonal = Math.sqrt(diagonal);
    return diagonal;
}



//A ".copy()" method that returns a rectangle of identical size.
public void copy(){ 
    Rectangle rectangleCopy = new Rectangle(width,height);
    rectangleCopy.setWidth(width); //set width to width of rectangleCopy
    rectangleCopy.setHeight(height); //set height to height of rectangleCopy
}



//A ".scale()" method that accepts a single double argument, and scales the instance rectangle by that amount.  For example, a 4X3 rectangle with .scale(2.0) applied to it should become 8X6 in size.
public void scale(){
    System.out.println("By what scale would you like to multiply?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double scale = scan.nextDouble();

    width = width * scale;
    height = height * scale;
}




//A ".doubleIt()" method which should double the area of the rectangle, without changing its aspect ratio (the ratio between the height and width).
public void doubleIt(){
    double area = getArea() * 2;
    height = area / (4*width);
    width = area / (4*((height) * (4*width / area)));        
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Alright first issue I spotted:

```
//One one-arg constructor that takes a Rectangle as an argument, and constructs as new Rectangle of identical size
public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangleDuplicate){ //calling rectangleDuplicate
    Rectangle d = new Rectangle();
    d.width = rectangleDuplicate.getWidth(); //set width to width of rectangleDuplicate
    d.height = rectangleDuplicate.getHeight(); //set height to height of rectangleDuplicate
}
```

You are creating a third rectangle d within the constructor for the second rectangle. It should be:

```
//One one-arg constructor that takes a Rectangle as an argument, and constructs as new Rectangle of identical size
public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangleDuplicate){ //calling rectangleDuplicate
    this.width = rectangleDuplicate.getWidth(); //set width to width of rectangleDuplicate
    this.height = rectangleDuplicate.getHeight(); //set height to height of rectangleDuplicate
}
```

Side note: try to always use this. when working with attributes of an object, it makes the code easier to read. Someone else doesn't have to think if you are trying to change the current object attributes or not.

Second issue:

This doesn't actually change the attributes of the rectangle, it just prints the values.

```
//A ".rotate()" method that reverses height and width of the instance rectangle.
public boolean rotate(){
    double newWidth = height;
    double newHeight = width;
    System.out.println("The new width is: " + newWidth + "\n" + "The new height is: " + newHeight);
    return true;
}
```

This makes the change:

```
//A ".rotate()" method that reverses height and width of the instance rectangle.
public boolean rotate(){
    double newWidth = height;
    double newHeight = width;

    // Access the rectangle attributes and change them to the new values
    this.height = newHeight;
    this.width = newWidth;

    System.out.println("The new width is: " + this.width + "\n" + "The new height is: " + this.height);

    // Why do you need a return? Is it part of the testing?
    return true;
}
```

Third issue:

```
//A ".copy()" method that returns a rectangle of identical size.
public void copy(){ 
    Rectangle rectangleCopy = new Rectangle(width,height);
    rectangleCopy.setWidth(width); //set width to width of rectangleCopy
    rectangleCopy.setHeight(height); //set height to height of rectangleCopy
}
```

You do not return the new rectangle. It gets discarded after the method has run.

The constructor you created for these inputs is already setting the height and width. You do not need to set them again afterwards.

Applying fixes:

```
//A ".copy()" method that returns a rectangle of identical size.
public Rectangle copy(){ 
    Rectangle rectangleCopy = new Rectangle(width,height);
    return rectangleCopy;
}
```

These are all the issues I could find so far.

EDIT: How I would test.

For example testing copy()

```
Rectangle result = i.copy();
// Check if height and width of the new rectangle have been initialized
// to the values of width and height of Rectangle i
System.out.println(result.getWidth());
System.out.println(result.getHeight());
```

Comment: "  // Why do you need a return? Is it part of the testing?
    return true;"

The reason there is a return statement in this line and again above is because for some reason the method comes up with an error if i don't have a return statement... 


also, is the 'void' the issue in my .copy and .scale and .doubleIt methods? because i cant pull anything in my tester...

Comment: Well copy returns and object of type Rectangle right now. You can't print an object. Scale and doubleit change the width and height of the Rectangle but does not return anything. Should it return an output of some sorts?

Comment: Rotate gives an error without return because you put the function call within a print statement. You should rather check the Rectangle after the rotate in your tester and see if w/h changed. The boolean you return does not mean anything logically it just satisfies the syntax error.

Comment: My .copy section is returning a strange error "Rectangle@17d10166" which is worrying.

  Also, my .scale is not allowing my input to be used. Its returning nothing at all.  

The only other issue I think I am having at the moment is that the rectangle dublicate will not display when called in the tester...

Comment: That is not an error that is the object: Rectangle@17d10166. You told Java to print the object it is printing the object, not the dimensions of it. If you do copy().getHeight() it should print the height of the new rectangle.

Comment: I guess I am a little confused as far as how I would test then to see if these specific methods are operating correctly.

Comment: You have to check the object's attributes that are created/modified by the methods. For the methods that give you back the area  you can just return the area and print it.

Comment: I added an example on how I would test copy().